# How can I keep linefeed when parsing with TagSoup?

Tags: jsoup

My question is very simple and short:
is there any way to keep linebreaks using JSoup to extract text?
When I use the .text() method all the 
 tags seem to be ignored. If i replace the 
 tags with "\n" and parse it again for .text() output these linebreaks are also ignored. 
So, is this doable? Or should I implements something of my own, or try to use some other HTML parser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can clean your html and leave only `<br>` and `<p>` tags(or only  `<br>` ) and then just replace this tags with "\n"